# Can I put a loop to check the letter's position in English alphabet instead of using if statement for every letter? (C)

Tags: c, loops, if-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char a;
do{
    printf("Enter an uppercase alphabet: ");
    scanf(" %c", &a);

} while(a < 'A' || a > 'Z');

for(int i=1;i<=1;i++)
{
  if(a=='A')
    printf("Alphabet number is 1");
  else if(a=='B')
    printf("Alphabet number is 2"); //and so on

}
```

}

Is there any way to loop it to print the letter number in English alphabet instead of using if statement for every letter?

Comment: Don't loop; use math. Hint: How does `a < 'A'` actually work? What happens if you assign `a` to an `int`?

Comment: Check the position of `A` in an ASCII table and do the math.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the standard C function `strchr`. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *alphabet =
    {
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    };

    char c;

    do
    {
        printf( "Enter an uppercase alphabet: " );
        scanf( " %c", &c );
    } while ( strchr( alphabet, c ) == NULL );

    printf( "The alphabet number of the character %c is %d\n",
            c, ( int )( strchr( alphabet, c ) - alphabet ) + 1 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter an uppercase alphabet: Z
The alphabet number of the character Z is 26
```

To reduce the number of calls of the function `strchr` you can introduce one more variable of the type `const char *`. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *alphabet =
    {
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    };

    char c;
    const char *p;

    do
    {
        printf( "Enter an uppercase alphabet: " );
        scanf( " %c", &c );
    } while ( ( p = strchr( alphabet, c ) ) == NULL );

    printf( "The alphabet number of the character %c is %d\n",
            c, ( int )( p - alphabet ) + 1 );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign to int:

```
int letter = a - 'A' + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand on @Tarik's answer a bit.

The [**American Standard Code for Information Interchange**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii) known as **ASCII,** is the standard from which modern character encodings are derived.

This encoding, unlike some others before it, places the 26 Latin-alphabet characters of each case together in a sequential range of numbers. Thus, 'A' has a numeric value, 'B' has a value one higher than 'A', 'C' has a value one higher than 'B', and so on. The same is true for 'a' .. 'z', although their numeric values are different.

Because of this, you can do a lot of very fast processing of basic latin characters using simple mathematical expressions. For example, upper- and lower-case letters differ by one bit, so you can switch between them by toggling that bit.

And, of course, you can take advantage of the sequential numeric range property to compute an expression that yields the number you want.

Specifically, if you treat the characters as integer types (which they are, but you should add a cast to make clear to the reader what you are doing), you will find that:

```
'0' - '0' == 0
'9' - '0' == 9

'A' - 'A' == 0
'Z' - 'A' == 25

'a' - 'a' == 0
'z' - 'a' == 25

'a' > 'A' (counterintuitive!)
'A' > '0'
```

This means you can get an "ordinal" number for the alphabetic letters by adding one to the expression:

```
char ch = 'Q'; // or any letter, really
int ordinal_number = (int)ch - 'A' + 1;
printf("Alphabet number is %d\n", ordinal_number);
```

Comment: @aghast This is a wrong approach because in the EBCDIC coding it is not necessary that characters follow each other without gaps.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin fixed! Thanks!

Comment: So long as it is limited to ASCII, it works fine. But that should be noted. EBCDIC throws punctuation in the middle of characters.